# hola buenas tengo una busqueda en mongo dentro de una funcion y querria que la funcion me haga el return del resultado de la busqueda

Tags: mongodb, function

hola buenas tengo una búsqueda en Mongo dentro de una función y necesito que la función me haga el return del resultado de la búsqueda pero la variable siempre me sale undefined al ser la búsqueda asíncrona no se como hacer que el return espere.

Este es el código:

```
const mongodb = {

    mejores_fotos: async (req, res) => {
        var fotos
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db(mydb);
            dbo.collection(col_me_gusta_fotos).find({}).toArray(async function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    fotos = 1
                    db.close()

                } else {

                    fotos = user.mejores_fotos1(result)
                    console.log(fotos)

                    // console.log(fotos)

                    db.close();
                }
            })

        });


        return fotos
    }
}
```

Comment: como veis la funcion mejores_fotos e la que quiero q haga el return para tener fotos en el lugar desde donde la llamo, el console.log de fotos me sale bien pero el return lo hace antes de que se guarde la busqueda, tengo todos los exports necesarios y demas

Comment: Tienes 2 opciones, o retornar una promesa (Promise) que se resuelva cuando consigas el valor, o usar `await` para llamar al `MongoClient.connect` y llamar al `collection.find`

Comment: ya lo he intentado y nada no espera

Comment: Entonces algo estás haciendo mal...